# What range of values of lambda does the mean of $Y$ converge? What is the mean in that case?

Tags: probability-theory

$X$ is an exponential RV with parameter lambda and $Y = e^x$. So, I found the density of $Y$ to be $\lambda y^{-\lambda}e^{-y}$. Then to find the range of $\lambda$ where the mean converges, do we just take the integral of the mean from zero to infinite and see where it would converge? Is that the correct process so far?

Answer (score 1):

Your density is not correct.  If $Y$ is a one-to-one function $g$ of another random variable $X$--that is, if $Y = g(X)$ for some invertible function $g$, then $$f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \left| \frac{dg^{-1}}{dy} \right|.$$  In your case, $$f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}, \quad x > 0,$$ and $Y = g(X) = e^X$, hence $X = g^{-1}(Y) = \log Y.$  Given this, what is your density of $Y$?

Now consider the *support* of $Y$:  namely, if $X > 0$, then what are the possible values of $Y$?  Call the support $\Omega$.

Next, consider the expectation of $Y$:  you could integrate it directly via the formula $$\operatorname{E}[Y] = \int_{y \in \Omega} y f_Y(y) \, dy.$$  For what values of the parameter $\lambda$ would this interval converge?

Alternatively, you may do the computation directly via the moment generating function of the random variable $X$:  recall that $$M_X(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{tX}],$$ for all $t$ for which such an expectation is defined.  But since $Y = e^X$, it is easy to see that $$\operatorname{E}[Y] = M_X(1).$$  Now recall that the MGF of an exponential distribution with rate parameter $\lambda$ is $$M_X(t) = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda - t}, \quad t < \lambda.$$  So, under what conditions of $\lambda$ would this MGF exist at $t = 1$?

Answer (score 0):

By the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) we have
$$E(e^X)=\int_0^\infty e^x \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx.$$
Since $e^x e^{-\lambda x}=e^{-(\lambda-1)x}$, the integral converges if and only if $\lambda\gt 1$.

Calculation of the integral, when it converges, is straightforward. We get $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-1}$.